# Are the any ways to configure WebStorm not to create new Run/Debug configuration when I run a single test or a test suit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, webstorm

If I run a single test or test suit from code editor IDE creates new Run/Debug Configuration. It's very convenient during the development to run only tests you need, but it ends up with dozens of useless Run/Debug Configurations in the list.

Are the any way configure WebStorm not to create new configuration every time I run tests using the right click on the tests or click the run button on the gutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. In Webstorm, running apps is only possible through the run configurations. When running from right-click menu/gutter, Webstorm auto-creates temporary configurations for each test; these configurations are deleted automatically (replaced with newer ones) once the max number of the temp configurations is reached

Comment: Actually it is possible by setting the mentioned max number to 0.